# How can I get Location Specific time and date using angular?

Tags: angular

All,

I found getLocaleDateFormat via angular.io. But, I have no idea how to use it.

This the link- https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleDateFormat.

Has anyone here used this function? If so, please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal date function in javascript itself will give the location specific date and time

```
    date : Date = new Date();
    today = Date.now();
```

You can also use date pipes in angular to format the date and time

```
<!--output 'Monday, June 15, 2015'-->
    <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>

    <!--output '9:43 AM'-->
    <p>The time is {{today | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
```

You can also display the date in french and other languages by [importing and registering locale](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes) in app.module.ts

app.module.ts

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(localeFr);
```

Template to display date in french

```
<!--output 'Lundi 15 Juin 2015 à 09:03:01 GMT+01:00'-->
    <p>The full date/time in french is: {{today | date:'full':'':'fr'}}</p>
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-internationalization)

Comment: Just to add to this, you can also use https://momentjs.com/ to manipulate date objects with ease

Comment: what is the best practice, store different time zone for enterprice application?

Comment: You can display the date with above methods, if you want to store the date in back end use UNIX epoch (number of seconds elapsed since 1970-01-01) or a UTC timestamp (no timezone or daylight saving time information). Every time convert this to current time in front end.